# Fetching data from msssql server using python

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch data from mssql server using python and one of the columns is coming with UUID. The data is getting fetched in the form of list of dictionaries. And the first column value i.e. the value for first key is having UUID data.

```
data = [{
  'AGENCY_ID': UUID('cbaf8fb4-7ada-4f4c-9726-fea39ed638f0'),
  'EINVOICE_CODE': '',
  'AGENCY_NAME': 'Zuru Inc.',
  'MAIN_PHONE_NUMBER': '',
  'FAX_NUMBER': '',
  'WEBSITE': '',
  'DEFAULT_BILLING_CYCLE_INT': 235,
  'DEFAULT_BILLING_CALENDAR_INT': 128,
  'DEFAULT_CASH_COMMISSION': 0.0,
  'DEFAULT_TRADE_COMMISSION': 0.0,
  'EXTERNAL_AGENCY_CODE': '',
  'MICR_CODE': '',
  'ROW_STATE': 1,
  'CREATE_DATE': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 18, 15, 45),
  'CREATE_BY': 'ObjectServer_KIDS_APP01/ongh004:SWNA\\$woadmin:dbo',
  'UPDATE_DATE': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 18, 15, 44, 59, 290000),
  'UPDATE_BY': 'ObjectServer_KIDS_APP01/ongh004:SWNA\\$woadmin:dbo',
  'UPDATE_COUNT': 0,
  'IS_PENDING': 0,
  'EI_EXPORT_TYPE': 6,
  'AGENCY_REPORTING_NAME': 'Zuru Inc.',
  'DUNS_NUMBER': '',
  'TCODE': '',
  'AGENCY_EXTERNAL_ID': '',
  'MAIN_ADDRESS_INT': 2250,
  'GLOBAL_AGENCY_ID': None,
  'STATION_ARRAY': b '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f',
  'LOCKBOX_PARENT_INT': None,
  'AGENCY_TYPE_INT': 774,
  'AGENCY_GROUP': '',
  'OVERRIDE_CASH_PAYMENT_TERMS_INT': None,
  'DEFAULT_OPTIONAL_EDI_CODES': ''
}]
```

**This is what i am trying.**

```
rec = [dict(row) for row in list]
for x in rec:
    print(x['AGENCY_ID'])
```

It is giving correct print value as **cbaf8fb4-7ada-4f4c-9726-fea39ed638f0**

While writing the data into JSON file, it is giving "none" in the place of string changed UUID data. Is there any way i can have that data write without "none" and having the proper value?

Comment: Post your code for how you are writing the JSON file, because thats probably where the issue is, since you said it's printing the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `x[''AGENCY_ID]` is of the type `UUID` and not a string. You need to cast it to a string using `str` function. For example:

`agency_id_str = str(x['AGENCY_ID'])`

Comment: yes, i tried this but this will give the values for that columns as "UUID('cbaf8fb4-7ada-4f4c-9726-fea39ed638f0')"  because it has become a string

Comment: can you tell me the type of `x['AGENCY_ID']`, by doing this: `print(type(x['AGENCY_ID']))`

Comment: its UUID..
<class 'uuid.UUID'>

Comment: now instead of the above line, add two lines: `str_ = str(x['AGENCY_ID']) print(str_)` and check if it's the required output...

Comment: its still the same....
i am getting the correct output for printing the vaue of first key value pair of dictionary..
but when i am trying to write it .. its not working and the output is coming with UUID...
here is piece of code i am trying..
    **def myconverter(self, obj):
        """ to convert datetime.datetime for values to be dumped in json """
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.__str__()**

        **rec = [dict(row) for row in cur.fetchall()]
        fulldata = ndjson.dumps(rec, default=self.myconverter)**

Comment: ADD the following lines in your myconverter function, that is add it after your datetime if block: `if isinstance(obj, uuid.UUID): return str(obj)`

Comment: even after **import uuid4 from uuid **   ...............getting error: name 'uuid' is not defined

Comment: just `import uuid`

Comment: try this: `def myconverter(self, obj):
    """ to convert datetime.datetime for values to be dumped in json """
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        return obj.__str__()
    if isinstance(obj, uuid.UUID):
            return obj.__str__()`

Comment: I successfully emulated your situation and I got a `null` for 'AGENCY_ID' as well. Then I edited the myconverter function as above and it is giving me the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your UUID var to a string before writing

```
foo = str(x['AGENCY_ID'])
```